# Is it compulsory to upload app in playstore for ruuning admob ads ? How can I show admob ads without publishing app on play store

Tags: admob

**Test Unit ID is working Properly**

My Admob Appis still in Review stage. It has been 1 week.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it's compulsory to upload app on Play Store if you want to monetize it, but ad IDs will be verified in 24 hours..**